# How to set libcurl to use poll()

Tags: linux, curl, select, libcurl, epoll

I'm trying to understand how to set Curl to be compiled using poll() instead of select().
(I have 2 Curl versions 7.45.0 and 7.61.1 that i need to set)

I can't find a "--with-poll" argument for ./configure,
I see only HAVE_POLL & HAVE_FINE_POLL definition with no idea where and how to set them..

Can someone help?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

curl's configure script will detect which system calls that work and will prefer poll() to select(). If you're not happy with the selection it does, beware that you're then outsmarting the curl developers and I hope you know what you're doing.

You can manually edit `lib/curl_config.h` post-configure. Make sure both `HAVE_POLL` and `HAVE_POLL_FINE` are defined and curl will then build to use poll() rather than select().

Comment: Hi Daniel,
I saw the 4 checks it does for poll, can you refer me to its decision making? i don't see a reason why it decides to work with select(), maybe fixing this will be more elegant.
If not i will add the parameters as you suggested.

Thanks!!

Comment: This is not the right forum to discuss details in curl's configure script.